# Как корректно вывести дробное число?

Tags: c++, qt

Здравствуйте!

Реализую проект на Qt. Пытаюсь вывести дробь, знаменатель которой не является степенью двойки (19 знаков после запятой). Например, 1/5 = 0,2000000000000000111.

Понятно, что такой вид - особенность представления чисел с плавающей точкой в C++. Но как вывести доступный для пользователя результат (1/5 = 0,2)? Формат вывода желательно не менять.

Пользуюсь следующим методом для вывода числа.

```
QString MainWindow::numberFormat(const double &number)
{
    QString str = QLocale::system().toString(number, 'f', 21);
    return str.remove(QRegExp(",?0+$"));
}
```

Прошу вашей помощи, заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я в своё время нашёл только один удобный выход из этой ситуации. Нужно реализовать собственный алгоритм деления числителя на знаменатель "уголком", как в школе, выводя одну десятичную цифру результата за другой. Получив строку нужной длины из цифр после запятой, удаляем нули на конце.

Код такой функции предельно прост (псевдокод, из головы):

```
void div (unsigned int num, unsigned int denom, size_t n) {
    printf ("%u,", num/denom);  // Целая часть
    num %= denom;   // Дробная часть.
    while (n-- > 0) {  // n - сколько нужно цифр.
        num *= 10;
        unsigned int d = num/denom;
        printf ("%u", d);
        num -= d*denom;
    }
}
```

Разумеется, вместо `printf` вам нужно что-то другое, например, сохранение цифр в строку или что вы там собираетесь делать, я не знаю.

Comment: все бы хорошо, только у меня числа могут быть еще и типа double

Comment: Кто мешает умножать их на 10 до тех пор, пока они не станут целыми? С другой стороны, если где-то возникает вопрос точности, то значит нужно с самого начала всё делать в рациональных дробях, а не в `double`. Даже если человек ввёл число типа `3,14` можно сразу на входе превратить его в `314/100`. Вообще не вижу проблемы.

Answer (score 3):

Ну прочтите документацию - вы же пытаетесь вывести 21 знак (`toString(number, 'f', 21)`). Зачем? Уберите точность вывода до реальной. Думаю, предлагаемых по умолчанию 6 знаков, как говорится, за глаза хватит... А то и меньше.

Comment: понятно, что 21 знак. У меня калькулятор, мне нужно вывести именно в таком формате.

Comment: В таком случае берите библиотеку для вычисления с точностью в 40 знаков, и отрезайте 21. Не окажитесь только в [этой ситуации](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UoKlKx-3FcA).

Comment: @Harry, ну, вы же эксперт - вы же все можете! :)